# Coin changing using Dynamic Programming

Tags: java, dynamic-programming

Coin changing is a popular interview question. Essentially the question means given a set of coin denominations and a total how many ways can one get the total provided there's an infinite supply of each denomination of coin.

This is my code.
The logic is every time I pick a coin the problem reduces to solving for the total minus the coin.

```
public static int numberOfWays(int total, int[] options){

        int[][] memo = new int[options.length][total+1];

        for (int i = 0; i <memo.length ; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j <memo[i].length ; j++) {

                if(i == 0)  memo[i][j] = 1;
                else if(options[i] > j ) memo[i][j] = memo[i-1][j];
                else memo[i][j] = memo[i-1][j] + memo[i][j - options[i]];
            }
        }
        return memo[options.length-1][total];
    }
```

This works on a test case of `total = 5 and options = 1, 2, 3`
But fails `total = 10 and options = 2, 5, 3, 6`

Can someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What is the result of each run? Also, does order matters or not, does 1+2+2=5 is the same as 2+2+1?

Comment: http://algorithms.tutorialhorizon.com/dynamic-programming-coin-change-problem/

Comment: @GershonPapi order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, it's good to write out a statement of what each array element represents:

> `memo[i][j]` represents how many ways to make the total amount `j` given only coins in denominations `options[0]`, `options[1]`, ..., `options[i]`.

Now, from that you appear to have derived a few laws:

1. `memo[0][j]` is `1` for all `j`
2. for `i` greater than 0, `memo[i][j]` is the same as `memo[i-1][j]` whenever `options[i] > j`
3. for `i` greater than 0, `memo[i][j]` is `memo[i-1][j] + memo[i][j - options[i]]` whenever `options[i] <= j`

Your problem is that the first of these laws isn't true. (the second two are)

The statement "`memo[0][j]` is `1` for all `j`" only holds if `options[0]` is `1`. If `options[0]` isn't `1`, then `memo[0][j]` is 1 when `j` is a multiple of `options[0]`, and 0 when it isn't. Using only coins of denomination `2`, you can't make 5 cents, so you should have (with the second set of data) `memo[0][5] == 0`, but your program says `memo[0][5] == 1`. This then throws off all your subsequent calculations.

So I'd modify your program to say:

```
            if(i == 0) { if (j % options[i] == 0) memo[i][j] = 1;
                         else memo[i][j] = 0; }
            else if(options[i] > j ) memo[i][j] = memo[i-1][j];
            else memo[i][j] = memo[i-1][j] + memo[i][j - options[i]];
```

(Though on a purely stylistic note, I find that `if`/`else` statements that don't use braces even for a single statement are asking for errors)